# Hiding assembly classes

Tags: c#, .net

I have one assembly library that contains a class called "Architecture". In another assembly i have the class called "ArchitectureManager" that helps me to implement some specific class types of that current assembly.

Finally i have a third assembly project that needs "ArchitectureManager", the problem comes how to hide "Architecture" from this third assembly project, since the second assembly needs it, also i cant just merge project two into project one.

Here is a snippet for further clarification:

```
//Assembly one
public class Architecture
{
}

//Assembly two
public class ArchitectureManager
{
  //Implement some Architecture class methods
}

//Asembly three needs ArchitectureManager but doesnt need to know about Architecture.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute for your assembly containing `Architecture`. You mark it as `internal` and allow it to be visible only to your other assembly.

See this MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

You can also see other questions tagged here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internalsvisibleto

Is there a specific reason why your `Architecture` object cannot be visible to other classes though? I rarely do this myself..

Comment: Architecture methods return information that is only meant to be processed by ArchitectureManager, so i want to delegate all the heavy work and possible "bug" production to the second assembly.

Comment: Would there be any reason then that it can't be included in the same directory as `ArchitectureManager` if it is only ever going to be used by it?

Comment: ArchitectureManager belongs to a different project and uses specific delegates and types that are not on the project that uses "Architecture" class. They are both library, but one extends to the other functionality, but your solution of InternalVisibleTo is good, thanks :)